# DateTimeFormatter for patterin MM/yy

Tags: java, java-8

I got this error when I do this

```
LocalDate.parse(expirationDate,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/yy");

java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '09/14' could not be parsed at index 5
```

I have test with the builder but I don't know how to do it?

Someone had some clue ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

`LocalDate` needs to contain day. If you don't plan to provide it you can use `YearMonth` instead.

```
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.parse("09/14",DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/yy"));
```

You can later build LocalDate with some day value like

```
LocalDate firstDay = yearMonth.atDay(1);
```

Comment: @ Pshemo If I want to parse with two pattern ? How I can figure it ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I want to parse YearMonth with two pattern "MM/yy" but my user can give me that "m/Y"

Comment: I am still not sure if I understand you correctly. If you want to allow user to provide pattern then there is not much to do except trying to parse it and in case of exception inform user that pattern was wrong. You can also create some set of correct patterns and compare pattern from user with them. If it will not be one of them ask for other pattern.

Comment: You can also try to define some rules which user pattern should apply. I can try helping you with implementing such rules, but first I would need to know what you want to allow and what should be forbidden.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90749/discussion-between-alexandre-picard-lemieux-and-pshemo).